# Лазерная система для замера времени спортсменов

Tags: java, android

Этот вопрос, наверное, не совсем по теме сайта, но всё-таки моя проблема имеет что-то общее с программированием.

**Проблема:** у меня возник вопрос, можно ли из подручных средств собрать лазерную систему, чтобы замерять время спортсменов бегунов при стартах по команде.

В моей голове это выглядит так: есть некая установка из двух компонентов, которая стоит на финишной черте. Первый компонент - обычная лазерная указка на подставке. Второй - некий элемент, который принимает в себя лазер. При запуске приложения спортсменам даются команды для старта и начинается отсчёт времени. Когда спортсмен пересекает лазер на финише, тот самый принимающий элемент передает, что сигнал от лазера перестал поступать, и тогда время останавливается.

Основная проблема заключается как раз в этом самом принимающем элементе. Я даже не знаю, как это можно назвать. Если кто-то имел дело с чем-то подобным, ваша помощь будет неоценима

**P.S.** приложение предполагается писать под `android`.

**UPD**: после некоторого ресерча наткнулся на так называемые фотоприемники, которые можно подключить к Ардуино и таким образом получать данные. К сожалению опыта работы с Ардуино не было. Можно ли вообще работать с ним на `java`?

Comment: Мысль верная, вот почитайте https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%88

Comment: Это тоже пригодится https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80

Comment: Спасибо, как раз информацию про подобные штуки гугл и выдал, но все ещё не до конца понимаю как получать от них сигналы

Comment: Ну как, всё просто - свет падает на резистор одно сопротивление, не падает другое (соответственно ток на выходе). Можешь лампочку/светодиод присоединить.

Comment: Да, уже разобрался, посмотрев пару видео по Ардуино. С кодом для Ардуино все понятно, но не понимаю как реализовать передачу сигнала на андроид. Есть блютуз адаптеры для Ардуино, но тут все упирается в мое плохое знание андроида. Примеры, которые нашел в интернете, для меня пока что непонятные. Есть ли какой-то супер простой способ для чайников? Может будет проще использовать проводное соединение

Comment: Ищите АЦП ардуино блютуз, на андройде, соответственно, как работать с блютуз)